# Windows Vista Laptop won't sleep automatically

Tags: laptop, windows-vista, sleep

I have an Acer Laptop running Vista Home edition.  Try as I might I cannot get it to sleep automatically after a period of inactivity.  I've been making changes in the Select a Power Plan dialog, choosing Balanced and then clicking on Change Plan settings.

I can get the monitor to turn off but the sleep doesn't happen.
I have also gone to Advanced Settings under power options and chosen the Turn off hard disk after 'x' minutes option to no avail.

All this is for "plugged in" since I rarely unplug my laptop.

I can manually make it sleep, i.e. use the start button, click on the arrow to the right of the lock icon and then choose sleep.

I found a thread with a similar problem that pertains to Win 8 but many of the commands that I am asked to try like powercfg -energy don't appear to work in Vista.

`powercfg -lastwake` tells me this but not sure how to interpret that.

```
C:\Users\AllUsers>powercfg -lastwake
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Device
    Instance Path: ACPI\PNP0C0E\2&daba3ff&3
    Friendly Name:
    Description: ACPI Sleep Button
    Manufacturer: (Standard system devices)
```

Comment: @Nazeeh - not sure what  you want me to do.  I have been experimenting by setting it to one minute (like in the example with powercfg).  It still won't sleep automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the duration to "put the computer to sleep" as low as you can on Windows Vista. I am running Windows 8 and my lowest time is 1 min. What I believe is Windows Vista will also have the same setting as  Windows 8.